# Replace string characters with their word index

Tags: python-3.x, string, nlp

Note the two consecutive spaces in this string:

```
string = "Hello there  everyone!"

for i, c in enumerate(string):
    print(i, c)

 0 H
 1 e
 2 l
 3 l
 4 o
 5
 6 t
 7 h
 8 e
 9 r
10 e
11
12
13 e
14 v
15 e
16 r
17 y
18 o
19 n
20 e
21 !
```

How can I make a list `len(string)` long, with each value containing the word count up to that point in the string?

Expected output:  `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2`

The only way I could do it was by looping through each character, setting a `space=True` flag and increasing a counter each time I hit a non-space character when `space == True`.  This is probably because I'm most proficient with C, but I would like to learn a more Pythonic way to solve this.

Comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._

Answer (score 1):

I feel like your solution is not that far from being pythonic. Maybe you can use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) operator to iterate your string two by two and then just detect local changes (from a space to a letter -> this is a new word):

```py
string = "Hello there  everyone!"

def word_index(phrase):
  nb_words = 0
  for a, b in zip(phrase, phrase[1:]):
    if a == " " and b != " ":
      nb_words += 1
    yield nb_words

print(list(word_index(string)))
```

This also make use of [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) which is quite common in python (see the documentation for the [`yield` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions)). You can probably do the same by using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) instead of the for loop, but I'm not sure it wouldn't obfuscate the code (see the third item from [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3)). Here is what it would look like, note that I used a lambda function here, not because I think it's the best choice, but simply because I couldn't find any meaningful function name:

```py
import itertools

def word_index(phrase):
  char_pairs = zip(phrase, phrase[1:])
  new_words = map(lambda p: int(p[0] == " " and p[1] != " "), char_pairs)
  return itertools.accumulate(new_words)
```

This second version similarly to the first one returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-iterator). Note that using a iterators is usually a good idea as it doesn't make any assumption on whether your user want to instantiate anything. If the user want to transform an iterator `it` to a list he can always call `list(it)` as I did in the first piece of code. Iterators simply gives you the values one by one: at any point in time, there only is a single value in memory:

```py
for word_index in word_index(string):
    print(word_index)
```

Remark that `phrase[1:]` makes a **copy** of the phrase, which means it doubles the memory used. This can be improved by using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) which returns an iterator (and therefore only use constant memory). The second version would for example look like this:

```
def word_index(phrase):
  char_pairs = zip(phrase, itertools.islice(phrase, 1, None))
  new_words = map(lambda p: int(p[0] == " " and p[1] != " "), char_pairs)
  return itertools.accumulate(new_words)
```